# Is it possible to tunnel https traffic via ssh tunnel with standard ssh-programs?

Tags: ssh, tunnel, https

Can I reroute the https traffic (of an svn repository) via ssh-tunnel.

The problem is that the the services that use https don't work if I just create one tunnel for listening with e.g.:

```
ssh -L 12345:server.com:443 localhost
```

Do I have to do something else? The aim is to tunnel https://PROJECT.googlecode.com/svn/ where PROJECT is the project name.

Answer (score 18):

HTTPS connection can be redirected via SSH port forwarding - however the SSL/TLS certificate validation will fail in such cases as the host name does not match:

You are connecting to https://localhost:12345 but the server certificate contains the name server.com.

Instead of directly forwarding the HTTPS connection I would run an HTTP(s)/SOCKS proxy on the remote computer you are opening the SSH connection to. Then set-up the program you want to tunnel to use this proxy through port forwarding. This would be a clean solution.

Update: It seems like SVN can use HTTP proxies but not SOCKS proxies.
If want to do so you need an additional "socksifier" on your local system. See [Serverfault.com: How can I set proxy for subversion with ssh tunnel?](https://serverfault.com/questions/73475/how-can-i-set-proxy-for-subversion-with-ssh-tunnel)

Comment: Can I actually use this kind of approach: http://dltj.org/article/ssh-as-socks-proxy/? So in the googlecode case, I would have a local-computer -> socks-computer -> googlecode. And this "ssh -D" would be run on local computer: ssh -D 12345 [username]@[socks-computer]. Now I have to tell svn to use proxy at local-computer:12345. Do I need something else?

Comment: Cool, I did not know that OpenSSH already includes a SOCKS proxy. See also my updated answer.

Comment: You can get around the HTTPS certificate issue by adding the remote host to your local hosts file with ip address 127.0.0.1. Then you can actually use https://remotehost:12345 address but the traffic will still be directed to SSH tunnel.

Comment: @JuhaPalomäki you should add this as an answer

Answer (score 3):

To be able to work around the certificate DNS mismatch issue while accessing the remote server with SSH tunnel, I did the following:

1. Configure an SSH tunnel in putty so that local port 443 forwards
   traffic to the remote server `(L443 : <remote.server.com>:443 )`
2. Update `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` file to add an entry such as `127.0.0.1 <remote.server.com>`
3. If you are using HTTP proxy server (for example if you are working from a corporate proxy), then bypass the `<remote.server.com>` host from system proxy
4. Now you can access the remote server URL with `https://<remote.server.com>`

Comment: This solution assumes `putty` and Windows. On Linux SSH is configured in `~/.ssh/config` (doc in `man ssh_config`) and if you are root, you can modify `/etc/hosts` instead. This feels hackish, still.

Comment: You can just tell whatever client program you are using to ignore the "bad" certificate. Usually all programs have some options for that (eg. `-k` in `curl`). Since you are setting up tunnel to a well-known server, you can safely ignore warnings about certificate mismatch.

Answer (score 2):

For Linux one could just SSH dynamic port forwarding

Localhost `ssh -fND 1234 user-name@remote-ip-address-A`

Remote host `ssh -fNL 12345:remote-ip-address-B:443 remote-ip-address-A`

Open Firefox install FoxyProxy and set it up as shown in the screengrab.
[FoxyProxy settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6lAvT.png)

In Firefox click the FoxyProxy icon and select the proxy connection you just made. In the URL bar type https://127.0.0.1.

Additionally you could just bypass this whole thing and just use `sshuttle`.
Using `sshuttle`'s `-H` argument causes it to update your local `/etc/hosts` file as new remote hostnames are found. You will need this so that certificates will work properly.

```
sshuttle -H -vr user-name@remote-ip-address-A remote-net/ip-address-B
```

Answer (score 1):

Juha Palomäki's comment helped me.

My scenario is as follows:

`server-i-want-to-get-to.com` is only accessible via a certain list of IP addresses, my home network is not allowed, but the outgoing IP address of `my-server.com` (a server I control) is allowed.

So, I want to get to https://server-i-want-get-to.com/, using the outgoing IP address from `me@my-server.com`

On my laptop (or desktop), I add an entry to `/etc/hosts`

```
sudo vi /etc/hosts
```

```
127.0.0.1 server-i-want-get-to.com
```

Now, I `ssh` in to `myserver.com`, and use `dig` to find out the IP address of `server-i-want-to-get-to.com`

```
dig server-i-want-to-get-to.com
```

... and now from the `ANSWER SECTION` I know the IP address `XX.XX.XX.XX`

From the terminal on my laptop, establish an ssh tunnel

... pick a port not already in use, 8686 is just an example ...

```
ssh -L 8686:XX.XX.XX.XX:443 me@my-server.com
```

Now, I can go to https://server-i-want-to-get-to.com:8686/ in my browser.

Thanks to the `/etc/hosts` entry, there is no SSL Certificate error.

... it might be necessary to clear browser cache, or start with a fresh browser ...