# How do I forward a website that I can access on a remote machine, to my local machine?

Tags: ssh, proxy, socks-proxy

I have a virtual machine (Windows) that serves a website: test.example.com. I would like to access that from my local machine (Mac) using that exact URL. They are on the same VPN, and I can ssh into the VM.

I successfully set up a SOCKS proxy, and I was able to do everything I want to do, except it was extremely slow.

[This answer](https://superuser.com/a/1762757/1772910) got me very close, but I had to use test.example.com:8686. Having the port there doesn't work.

test.example.com is only available within the VM, it is only used for development

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want to be able to accomplish the same thing in the answer I linked, without having the port in the URL